# Nao estou conseguindo autenticar usuario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Não estou conseguindo fazer a autenticação de usuário, só está redirecionando para a parte onde "não é possível fazer o cadastro de usuário".

```
<?php 

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = MD5($_POST['senha']);
$connect = mysqli_connect('nome_do_servidor','nome_de_usuario','senha');
$db = mysqli_select_db('nome_do_banco_de_dados');
$query_select = "SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'";
$select = mysqli_query($query_select,$connect);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
$logarray = $array['login'];

  if($login == "" || $login == null){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('O campo login deve ser preenchido');window.location.href='cadastro.html';</script>";

    }else{
      if($logarray == $login){

        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse login já existe');window.location.href='cadastro.html';</script>";
        die();

      }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (login,senha) VALUES ('$login','$senha')";
        $insert = mysqli_query($query,$connect);

        if($insert){
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');window.location.href='login.html'</script>";
        }else{
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível cadastrar esse usuário');window.location.href='cadastro.html'</script>";
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: No último `else`, coloque `echo mysqli_error($connect)` para exibir a última mensagem de erro em MySQLi.

Comment: curiosidade, pode inverter a ordem dentro do parentesis `$select = mysqli_query($query_select,$connect);` não seria `$select = mysqli_query($connect,$query_select);`

Comment: Bem-vindo, não deixe de ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Correções feitas:

essas duas linhas

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('nome_do_servidor','nome_de_usuario','senha');
$db = mysqli_select_db('nome_do_banco_de_dados');
```

foram substituidas por uma linha

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('nome_do_servidor','nome_de_usuario','senha','nome_do_banco');
```

Tanto `$select = mysqli_query($query_select,$connect);` quanto `$insert = mysqli_query($query,$connect);` inverti a ordem dentro dos parêntesis.

Testei, funciona e segue o código completo.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('nome_do_servidor','nome_de_usuario','senha','nome_do_banco');

$query_select = "SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'";
$select = mysqli_query($connect,$query_select);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
$logarray = $array['login'];

if($login == "" || $login == null){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('O campo login deve ser preenchido');window.location.href='cadastro.html';</script>";
}else{
  if($logarray == $login){

    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse login já existe');window.location.href='cadastro.html';</script>";
    die();

  }else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (login,senha) VALUES ('$login','$senha')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

    if($insert){
      echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');window.location.href='login.html'</script>";
    }else{
      echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível cadastrar esse usuário');window.location.href='cadastro.html'</script>";
    }
  }
}
```